# How to select value/innerHTML of a certain <td> within a certain <tr>? Using Javascript only. No jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, row

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo1</td>
    <td>bar1</td>
    <td><input type="button" id="button1" onClick="get(this);"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo2</td>
    <td>bar2</td>
    <td><input type="button" id="button2" onClick="get(this);"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Goal:** To get buttons `button1` and `button2` to trigger the same `function get()` which should get the value of the first `<td>` in the same `<tr>` the button resides in. Which is, in this case: `foo1` and `foo2` respectively.

This is a rough outline of the function which should help understand what I'm trying to achieve-

```
function get(element){
  alert(element.tr.first_td.innerHTML);
}
```

I realize there was a jQuery solution to a similar problem. But I do not understand jQuery well enough to translate it back to JavaScript. If it is possible at all using JavaScript, please show me how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crawl up the `parentNode` twice to get to the `tableRow` element. From there, access the first `td` from the HTMLCollection of cells, and get the `innerHTML` value:

```
function find( element ) {
    alert( element.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML );
}​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/WuWnw/

Comment: Another way might be `element.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.innerHTML`, anything else? :-)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine There are a great number of ways :)

Comment: There isn't so many "effective" ways. Sure, let's not go back to the body and get down again, but I'm sure you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, since you have many `tr` and `td` tags right, so, you can do DOM Parsing. But you need to specify one `ID` for the table to get that table. For now lets call it `foo-table`.

```
var table = document.getElementById("foo-table");
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    alert(cells[i].innerHTML);
}
```

If you don't wanna give an ID and you are sure that there is only one table, then use this:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
var cells = table[0].getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    alert(cells[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Enjoy! Hope this helps! :) No `jQuery` or any other plugin. Pure JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="button1_value">foo1</td>
    <td>bar1</td>
    <td><input type="button" id="button1" onClick="get('button1_value');"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="button2_value">foo2</td>
    <td>bar2</td>
    <td><input type="button" id="button2" onClick="get('button2_value');"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You shoul identify what you want to get using an ID so that you can easily retrieve it. This also helps prevent the chance of getting erroneous data. If you give the component an id you should be able to use document.getElementById() to get that component.

```
function get(element){
  var obj = document.getElementById(element)
  alert(obj.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Efficient. It's a PITA to have to specific HTML though.

Comment: Actually the table was going to be dynamic. So although ID-fying would be possible, I'd rather keep it plain.